# Webpack error: configuration.module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'query'

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWUR04B42Hc, I know it has outdated content but I think a have translated it correctly to the latest version of *Webpack*, but it's giving me this error `configuration.module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'query'.`

*Full version*

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:
   object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
   -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
```

*My `webpack.config.js`*
const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './source/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Do anyone know what's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is very clear, there is no `query` option on `rule` configuration, you should use `options.presets`. See [usage](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#usage) for **Webpack v5**

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```